# FFMPEG Join two videos with different width

Tags: join, ffmpeg, command, width

I am trying to join two videos side by side.
I use this command, but it adds more pad that I need it:

```
ffmpeg -i video_1.mp4 -i video_2.mp4 -filter_complex '[0:v]pad=iw*2:ih:0:0[intv];[intv][1:v]overlay=W/2:0[vid]' -map [vid] -c:v libx264 -crf 22 -preset veryfast output.mp4
```

Is there any way to change the pad width so it is: input1 width + input2 width?
And also overlaying at the final of the first input width?

I mean, if video_1 width is 600px, and video_2 width is 200px, output video width should be 800px, and video_2 should start at (600, 0).

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Use the hstack filter:

```
ffmpeg -i video_1.mp4 -i video_2.mp4 -filter_complex '[0:v][1:v]hstack=2[vid]' -map [vid] -c:v libx264 -crf 22 -preset veryfast output.mp4
```

The hstack filter requires all inputs to have the same height.

---

If the inputs don't have the same height, then a longer workaround is required.

```
ffmpeg -i video_1.mp4 -i video_2.mp4 -filter_complex "color=d=0.1[c];
         [c][0]scale2ref[c][v1];[c][1]scale2ref=w=main_w+iw:h=max(main_h,ih)[c][v2];
         [c][v1]overlay=0:0[ol-vid1];[ol-vid1][v2]overlay=W-w:0,setsar=1"   out.mp4
```

This requires a mid-June 2017 or later version of ffmpeg.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, but they don't have the same height. Is it still possible?

Comment: Does the command have to be generic or can you craft it manually?

Comment: It should be generic, due to I don't know the exact size of each video

Comment: This can be done in a circuitous manner using a recent version of ffmpeg. It's a bit involved so I'll add it tomorrow.

Comment: That is true: `The hstack filter requires all inputs to have the same height.`

Comment: I'm getting `No such filter: 'ih)'` when I try the latter approach.

Comment: Inside the expression, escape the commas i.e. `main_h,ih` --> `main_h\,ih`